# React-native-vector-icons show obscure symbols

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm, icons

I've installed `react-native-vecotor`. And when using them, they showing obscure symbols. How to use this library ? Platform: Android

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

const SearchBar = () => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.background}>
            <Icon name="md-body" color='#000'  size={25} />
        </View>
    );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    background:{
        backgroundColor:'#F0EEEE',
        marginHorizontal: 15,
        height:45,
        borderRadius:5,
    }
});
export default SearchBar;
```

Comment: have you put the custom font in this directory: android/app/src/main/assets?

Comment: @mohsen.h no, How to put?

Comment: you must add iconmoon.ttf to manual in this directory and I think it does work.

Comment: @mohsen.h In directory android/app/src/main/assets/fonts many files with .ttf extension. Like AntDesign, FontAwesome

Comment: is there ionicons.ttf in the directory ?

Comment: @mohsen.h Yeah. All of .ttf file that need to raect-native-vector-icons

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202643/discussion-between-mohsen-h-and-bekanur98).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just reinstall project application from my device. It's works!

Answer (score 3):

If you are using react-native version 0.60++ then it must be the linking problem!

I was facing same after updating react-native, but solved by this, Follow my instructions.

1. Clean your gradlew (Optional but recommended)
   To clean gradle go to android folder and open cmd & run `gradlew clean`
2. Go to `android/app/build.gradle` add this at the end of file =>
   `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"`
3. Now re-compile (react-native run-android) It must be working now!..

Answer (score 1):

`Ionicons` has no element name `body`. You can check here [react-native-vector-icons](https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/)

```
<Icon name="ios-body" color='#000'  size={25} />
```